# $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable function, is $f(\frac{1}{x})$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

Defintion:

A function is measurable $\iff$ $\forall$ Borel set $F\subseteq\bar{\mathbb{R}}, f^{-1}(F)$ is Lebesgue-measurable set.

---

My attempt is use the composition of $f$ and $g=\frac{1}{x},f(\frac{1}{0})=0$, so we just need to prove that the set :
$$E = \{\frac{1}{x} : f(x)>c\} \text{is a Lebesgue-measurable set}, \forall c\in\mathbb{R}.$$
then every thing is done.

Then, I separate E into three parts: 
$$E = (E\cap(-\infty,-\delta]) \cup (E\cap(-\delta,\delta)) \cup (E\cap[\delta,+\infty)$$

As $g=\frac{1}{x}$ is locally Lipschitz continuous, the first part and third part is measurable, but i got stuck in the second part. How should i connect it with Caratheodory condition?

Any idea or Hint would be appreciated!

Comment: $f(\frac 1 0)=0$?

Comment: There's no need to define $f(\frac1x)$ at $x=0$. Just let the composition have domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}.$

Comment: @md2perpe yes, it doesn't matter on the $x=0$, just definition.

Answer (score 0):

The function $x\mapsto\frac1x:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and therefore measurable. The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to Y$ is measurable. The composition of measurable functions is measurable. Thus $x\mapsto f(\frac1x) : \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to Y$ is measurable.

Comment: The problem with your proof is OP is taking about Lebesgue measurability not Borel measurability.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy. So $x \mapsto \frac1x$ is measurable $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}) \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is measurable $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}),$ and then we can use composability of measurable functions.

Comment: There are two interpretations of Lebesgue measurability. Many authors define Lebesgue measurability of  a function from $\mathbb R$ into itself by  the condition $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R)$ for all Borel sets $B$. On SE I have seen people using the condition $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R)$ for all Lebesgue measurable sets $B$. OP has to  clarify this.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy That's right. The definition is the former one : $f$ is Lebesgue measurable if $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R})$ for all Borel sets $B$.

Comment: @md2perpe The definition of measurable function is on Borel sets, not general Lebesgue-measurable sets.